# Sails.js - how to update nested model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

```
attributes: {
    username: {
        type: 'email', // validated by the ORM
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    profile: {
        firstname: 'string',
        lastname: 'string',
        photo: 'string',
        birthdate: 'date',
        zipcode: 'integer'
    },
    followers: 'array',
    followees: 'array',
    blocked: 'array'
}
```

I currently register the user then update profile information post-registration.  How to I go about adding the profile data to this model?

I read elsewhere that the push method should work, but it doesn't.  I get this error: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'push'

```
        Users.findOne(req.session.user.id).done(function(error, user) {

            user.profile.push({
                firstname : first,
                lastname : last,
                zipcode: zip
            })

            user.save(function(error) {
                console.log(error)
            });

        });
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Zolmeister is correct. Sails only supports the following model attribute types

`string, text, integer, float, date, time, datetime, boolean, binary, array, json`

They also do not support associations (which would otherwise be useful in this case)

[GitHub Issue #124](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/124).

You can get around this by bypassing sails and using mongo's native methods like such:

```
Model.native(function(err, collection){

    // Handle Errors

    collection.find({'query': 'here'}).done(function(error, docs) {

        // Handle Errors

        // Do mongo-y things to your docs here

    });

});
```

Keep in mind that their shims are there for a reason. Bypassing them will remove some of the functionality that is otherwise handled behind the scenes (translating id queries to ObjectIds, sending pubsub messages via socket, etc.)

Comment: Not convinced this works - `collection.find` doesn't have a promise-style `done` method.

Comment: It may have changed in v0.10. If that's the case, it likely still follows the standard of passing the callback as the last argument to .find()

Answer (score 2):

Currently Sails doesn't support nested model definitions (as far as I know). You could try using the `'json'` type.
After that you would simply have:

```
user.profile = {
  firstname : first,
  lastname : last,
  zipcode: zip
})

user.save(function(error) {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: That's disappointing being that Sails is built for mongoDB... that's the advantage of using a document oriented DB.

Answer (score 1):

Too late to reply, but for others (as a reference), they can do something like this:

```
Users.findOne(req.session.user.id).done(function(error, user) {
  profile = {
            firstname : first,
            lastname : last,
            zipcode: zip
      };
  User.update({ id: req.session.user.id }, { profile: profile},         
        function(err, resUser) {
  });           
});
```