# I can't establish a simple association on Sails.js (relation model's field shows undefined)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js, model-associations

I've been trying a simple 'one way association' on v0.9.16 and later v.10.0.rc8. 
I'm guessing, I'm doing something wrong.
I have two collections on my MongoDB and I have two models and a controller such as following;

my User.js file;

```
module.exports = {

  connection: 'mongo',

  attributes: {

    username: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    encryptedPassword: {
        type: 'string' , 
        required: true
    },

    //one way association
    personel: {
      model: 'Personel'
    }  

  }
};
```

my Personel.js file;

```
module.exports = {

  connection: 'mongo',

  attributes: {
      name: 'string',
      phone: {
          mobile: 'string',
          office: 'string'
      },
      email: 'string',
      gender: 'string'
      department: {
          department_id: 'integer',
          department_name: 'string'
      },
      title: {
          title_id: 'integer',
          title_name: 'string'
      }
  }
};
```

my UserController.js file;

```
module.exports = {
show : function (req, res) {
User
.findOne(req.param('id'))
.populate('personel')
.exec(function(err, user) {
console.log(user);
});

}
```

Console writes 'undefined' for personel field;

```
{ username: 'jkidd',
personel_id: '1',
personel: undefined }
```

### Edit

To provide association I've just added following codes to my User model

```
//one way association
personel: {
  model: 'Personel'
}
```

and I'm trying to

```
show : function (req, res) {
   User
    .findOne(req.param('id'))
    .populate('personel')
    .exec(function(err, user) {
      if(err) return res.json(err, 400);
      if(!user) return res.json({ error: 'No User with that Id' }, 404);

      console.log(user);

      res.view({
        user : user
      });
    });            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the Association in your Personel.js:

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'mongo',
  attributes: {
    department_id: 'integer',
    department_name: 'string',
    owner: {
      model: "User"
    }
  },

 }
```

See for more Info: http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Models/Associations/OnetoOne.html

Hint: You dont need to config the _id - waterline handle that for you!

Edit:

**Also a Issue**

And you cannot use "nested attributes" (see: [How to translate models in Sails.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352813/how-to-translate-models-in-sails-js/24365200#24365200)). Change that also!

edit: you almost there... ;-)

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {

    username: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },

    encryptedPassword: {
        type: 'string' ,
        required: true
    },

    //one way association
    personel: {
        model: 'user'
    },

},
};
```

and your personel.js

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {

    name: 'string',

    email: 'string',

    gender: 'string',

    owner: {
        model: 'user',
    },

},

};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried "one way association". I've reviewed almost all of Sails and Waterline documents. If I don't use the _id field then the console gives an error like "throw new Error(error)    Error: Trying to create an association on model that doesn't have a Primary Key".  And Waterline comes included with Sails.  Unfortunately your solution doesn't work. Thanks anyway..

Comment: Also delete personel_id in your User-Model!

Comment: I've marked as comment lines personel_id, but result did not change. I I can get User model fields still personel field comes 'undefined'. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have Personels in your database with the right User-ID at owner?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I'am a newbie in front-end programming. I've been trying for 3 days! Yes. I have a personel its _id is 1. And I have a user its _id is 1.           

user collection;
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "username" : "jkidd",
    "passwaord" : "jkidd",
    "personel_id" : "1"
}

and 

Personel collection;
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "Jason Kidd"
}

Comment: Oh i see your have a few other mistakes.

Can you please post your hole Personel.js and User.js?
(simple edit your Question an delete the old parts)

Comment: I've written them above. Thank you again.

Comment: So: You dont add the association. See my first Post (owner: ...)

Comment: Unfortunately. It doesn't work for me. Still associated field seems 'undefined'.

Comment: I've tried another way associate because of I cannot use 'nested attributes'. Same result for me. 'user: undefined'.

Comment: I'm sorry. It doesn't for me. I'll install another new test environment and I will try again. If I find any reason about this error, I'll write here. Thank you for your kindness...

Comment: Waterline can't catch the existing records that is created previous. My problem is that :)   If I try create record with Waterline everything is OK...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a comment but cannot as my rep isn't high enough. As already stated. You missed the Association in your `Personel.js.`

With this in place waterline should link the models up but it isn't for some reason. I'd suggest removing your id attributes as these are likely confusing matters as you'll get `_id` added automatically for you which is what waterline will use for the associations.

In your code where you associate the personnel to user do so by setting `user.personnel = personnel.id`.

If you require more help can you post the `code/commands` you're using to associate the models too.

[EDIT]

With regards to nested attributes check [Sails.js - how to update nested model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780009/sails-js-how-to-update-nested-model)

Your User model should be as follows:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        username: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },

        encryptedPassword: {
            type: 'string' ,
            required: true
        },

        //one way association
        personel: {
            collection: 'personel',
            via: 'user',
        },

    },
};
```

And your personel model:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        name: 'string',

        email: 'string',

        gender: 'string',

        user: {
            model: 'user',
        },

    },

};
```

And just a little modification to your controller so that you can view the JSON output in browser:

```
module.exports = {

    show: function (req, res) {
        User2.find()
        .populate('personel')
        .exec(function(err, user) {
            console.log(user);
            return res.send(200, user);
        });

    },

}
```

[EDIT]

I've just realised you weren't talking about a one to many association, the above is that, not a one to one.

Your edited code looks find for the one to one join. How are you creating the models? I think that's your issue, you need something like:

```
Personel.create({ name: 'personel'}, function(err, createdPersonel) {
    User.create({ name: 'user', personel: createdPersonel.id }, function(err, createdUser) {
        res.send(200, createdUser )
    }
}
```

That's without error checking and assuming you're in a controller.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new in Sails. I'd tried your suggest before. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I guess I'm doing another wrong things. Thanks anyway..

Comment: But how were you trying to associate a a personnel to a user?

Comment: I've edited my first question above. To provide association I've just added following codes and I'm trying to ... .find(req.param('id')).populate('personel') ...
//one way association
personel: {
  model: 'Personel'
}

Comment: Actually I had tried 'one way association' same as with https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/associations.md#one-to-one-associations   For instance, the Personnel collection might has 100 personnels, but only 20 persons might have authorization to use this system. I thought that when I started. Thank you for your attention.